# Find variable in json php loop

Tags: php, json, search

I need to find a phone number in a json array with php. i was trying foreach but the issue is if the phone number is not found I get multiple records. Is there anyway to write the else so I only get 1 response. I need to post back if the phone is not found but it creates a record for each not found record.

My response looks like this

Not found

Not found

found

Not found

Not found

I need 1 Not found not multuple.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$usertype='x-cw-usertype: integrator';

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "/apis/3.0/company/contacts");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

             'Authorization: basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
             'clientId: ',

             $usertype,

 'Content-type: application/json'

       ));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json_contacts = json_decode($response, true);
//var_dump($json_contacts);

}

// Loop through Array
foreach ( $json_contacts  as $item ) { 


// If a phone number is found 
if ( $item['defaultPhoneNbr'] == '5551212' ) {  

   echo 'found <br>';
} 

// If phone is not found
else if  ( $item['defaultPhoneNbr'] != '5551212' ){ 


   echo 'Not found <br>';

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create variable for storing result. Like:

```
foreach ( $json_contacts  as $item ) { 

// Check item and the return value of  
// reset() function is equal then it  
// will be the first iteration 
if ( $item['defaultPhoneNbr'] == '6102070035' ) { 

    // Desplay the array element 

    $result = “found”;
    break;
 } 


// Check if item and return value of  
// end() function is equal then it 
// will be last iteration 
else if  ( $item['defaultPhoneNbr'] != '6102070035' ){ 


       $result = “not found”;
} 
}
```

Then just echo it.

```
  echo $result;
```

Comment: “Break” use if you dont want to continue in loop.

Comment: That seems to work, Not sure why but I tried break ealier and it seemed to be timing out my loop. i just redid the code and it seems to be working. Thanks alot